# How to instantiate a Python class in Julia?

Tags: python, julia

Here is my Python class:

```
class RoadSegInr(object):
    def __init__(self, tmc, road_num, shape_length):
        self.tmc = tmc
        self.road_num = road_num
        self.shape_length = shape_length
```

I have instantiated it to get

```
road_seg_inr = RoadSegInr(0, 0, 0)
```

I use the following code to save `road_seg_inr`:

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle
import gzip
proto = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL

def zdump(obj, f_name):
    f = gzip.open(f_name,'wb', proto)
    pickle.dump(obj,f)
    f.close()

def zload(f_name):
    f = gzip.open(f_name,'rb', proto)
    obj = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return obj

zdump(road_seg_inr, "road_seg_inr.pkz")
```

How can I use Julia to load `road_seg_inr` so that I can access its attributes?

Comment: Easiest is to just not use pickle, write to something more easily read like JSON.

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with JSON, but I think this makes sense.

Comment: Check this package -> https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl

Comment: To Reza: I have tried PyCall; error message indicates the class definition RoadSegInr is required but I feel it not easy to load RoadSegInr from a Python module, especially when having lots of its instantiations to load. pvg's comment actually solves the problem.

Comment: The class definition is required in python too.